# How to use teleric treeview control in asp.net mvc framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, treeview, telerik-mvc

I want to use telerik treeview in mvc, but i don't want to use kendo UI, and i can't fine any example of teleric treeview for mvc.

can any one help me or give me any example so i can learn and understand?

I want to use treeview with checkbox and list is like this...

```
{
pencil 
  *natraj
  *apsara
pen
  *bollpen
     >rotomak
     >add jel
  *Inkpen
Eraser
  *natraj
}
```

This type of list then how can i use teleriK treeview with mvc framework for insert and delete function?

it's relly need please give any example or sample code.

Comment: Why don't you want to use kendo ui according to telerik their mvc libary is obsolete and you should switch to kendo ui?

Comment: see i am using nopcommerce and in nopcommerce there is already Teleric UI so i think if i use kendo UI Then there is any issue is created, because Kendo UI and Teleric UI are both form same companies and for kendo UI i want to purces licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code:

```
@model YourModelTree
     @(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
                  .Name("TelerikTree")
                  .ShowCheckBox(true)
                  .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
                  {
                      mappings.For<YourModelTree>
                          (binding => binding
                              .ItemDataBound((item, modelItem) =>
                              {
                                  item.Text = modelItem.Name;
                                  item.Value = modelItem.Id.ToString();
                                  item.Expanded = true;
                                  item.Checked = true;
                              }).Children(c => c.Children));
                  })))
```

**Example of model Tree:**

```
 public class ModelTree
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<ModelTree>() Children {get;set;}
        public ModelTree Parent {get;set;}
    }
```

Also you can  check telerik [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-treeview-introduction.html) .If you have any question please ask me.

Comment: Can i use Telerik UI and Kendo UI both in same project? And Telerik UI Have Any Drag and Drop Control like kendo UI?

Comment: Yes you can but I will not recommend you  to do this , I like more telerik ui than kendo and Telerik UI is for free .For draganddrop check   .ShowCheckBox(true)
              .DragAndDrop(true)